# how to Access javascript Varibale in Angular js with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following code

```
<head>
<script>
    var sourceUrl = 'image url';

    </script>
</head>
```

and following HTML

```
<span style="background-image: url('{{sourceUrl }}{{myanotherangularVariableWhichisWorking}}');></span>
```

Now my Source URL is not coming here..

Any idea how to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your sourceUrl variable on the $scope object inside an angular controller, then tell your html element to be bound to the scope of that controller.